# PHP adding multiple objects to array

Tags: php

I have following php:

```
 $refined_results = array();

    $refined_results['First']    = $results[0];         
    $refined_results['Second']   = $results[1]; 
    $refined_results['Third']    = $results[2]; 
    $refined_results['Fourth']   = $results[3]; 
    $refined_results['Fifth']    = $results[4]; 
    $refined_results['Sixth']    = $results[5];
```

Is there a way to simplify this?

For example (totally wrong of course):

```
$refined_results['First','Second','Third']    = $results[0,1,2]; //Yup...
```

Comment: why do you want to call it first, second, third... ?

Comment: It's just arbitrary name that I gave. The query results have names that I need to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function:

```
$keys = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
$refined_results = array_combine($keys, $results);
```

Comment: I made another question from your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713683/php-targeting-specific-keys-in-array-combine

Answer (score 1):

```
$refined_results = array();
$keys = array('First', 'second', 'third');// you can add more
foreach($keys as $i=>$k) {
 $refined_results[$k] = $results[$i];
}
```